# How the default run() function in springboot maven project works

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am new to the Springboot framework, and I have some questions about the defualt run() function in the application.java file of the springboot maven project.
I'm trying to build a REST api with spring maven project. In specific, if I have a @Restcontroller class, when and how does the default run() function call an instantiated object of it? And how are the annotated classes like @Service, @RestController and @SpringBootApplication linked together when running the application? (like, what is the process of execution of all these components at runtime?) I know the controller class is used to host APIs, but what should I put in the @Service classes?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no magic in Spring. We can try to debug the code in our ide. Of course, we can do some homework before we start debuging. Read the reference of Srping may be a good start.

Comment: I think you're helped more with just following a few Spring tutorials with these questions. If you're interested how it works on the backend, read up on annotation processing, annotation scanning and dependency injection. You can then always browse through the Spring source code to see how that is all implemented.

Answer (score 1):

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation in the main application class combines the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@Configuration` and the `@ComponentScan` annotations.

When run, the static `run()` method starts the Spring Boot application:

`@ComponentScan` scans the main class package and subpackages for different `@Component` classes such as controllers, services and repos and registers them as beans in the ApplicationContext.

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` auto configures your application based on the included jars in classpath.

As far as components go:

`@RestController` as you said exposes the application's endpoints using `@RequestMapping` method annotations.

`@Service` holds the business logic and calls repository methods.

`@Repository` is data access object that connects to the databases.